# How can I widen and match those plots?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have such 3 plots. These shorter ones are plots with a) peaks (local maximums) b) down-peaks (local minimums). Problem is these plots don't match their father, because arrays' sizes are something about 40, when the big one has ~180. In each cell there's the value between 0 and 1. I'm using matplotlib to visualize these plots, but data operation can be whatever I want - pandas, numpy, lists. How can I widen these plots?

[image]

Edit:
Used code from below and you can see that these plots don't match, when they should, because these are local minimums and maximums of the main plot. Middle axis is frame. How can I match them?

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, len(fun), len(min_norm)), min_norm, 'b')
plt.plot(np.linspace(0, len(fun), len(max_peaks_vals)), max_peaks_vals, 'g')
plt.plot(fun, 'm')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Either you fill the arrays to the appropriate length with `None` values or you add further axes which have their own x-scale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if these are time series, it would be better to plot against the real `datetime` points instead of a range index.

If you do want to stretch the `x` values, use [**`np.linspace()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) where the left bound is 0 and right bound is the longest array's length.

```py
y1 = np.random.random(size=40) * 0.1
y2 = np.random.random(size=50) * 0.3
y3 = np.random.random(size=180)

left, right = 0, len(y3)
plt.plot(np.linspace(left, right, len(y1)), y1)
plt.plot(np.linspace(left, right, len(y2)), y2)
plt.plot(y3)
```

[image: stretched arrays]

Comment: Okay, done as above, but data doesn't match, when they should, because these are max and mins of the main function.